# Convert text column to timestamp in Amazon redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp, amazon-redshift, to-date

I have a text field "completed_on" with text values "Thu Jan 27 2022 11:55:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".
I need to convert this into timestamp.

I tried , **cast(completed_on as timestamp)** which should give me the timestamp but I am getting the following error in REDSHIFT

**ERROR: Char/varchar value length exceeds limit for date/timestamp conversions**

Answer (score 1):

Since timestamps can be in many different formats, you need to tell Amazon Redshift how to interpret the string.

From [TO_TIMESTAMP function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html):

> `TO_TIMESTAMP` converts a `TIMESTAMP` string to `TIMESTAMPTZ`.

```
select sysdate, to_timestamp(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as seconds;


timestamp                  | seconds
-------------------------- | ----------------------
2021-04-05 19:27:53.281812 | 2021-04-05 19:27:53+00
```

For formatting, see: [Datetime format strings - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html).